# mutate(across()) with external function that references other variables in current data frame without passing second argument

Tags: r, function, dplyr, across

I want to `mutate()` multiple variables with `across()`

1. using a function defined beforehand
2. that references other variables in the data frame but
3. needs only one argument (the variable to be mutated) and
4. does not hard code the environment for those variables inside the function.

For example, this code will add the variable `x` to each of `y` and `z`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Data to modify
dtmp = tibble(x = 1:4, y = 10, z = 20)

# Function to pass to mutate(across())
addx = function(col, added){col + added}

# Any of these works
dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), addx, added=x))
dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), ~addx(.x, x)))
dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), function(var){addx(var, x)}))
```

It is possible to avoid passing a second argument to `addx` inside `mutate(across())` by hard-coding the reference to `dtmp$x` in the global environment:

```
addx = function(col){col + dtmp$x}
dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), addx))
```

However, this solution is risky. For example, it would fail to behave as desired if the data frame were grouped (by some 4th variable) before the `mutate` call because `dtmp$x` would not be the same length as the subset of `y` or `z` within the group.

It seems like it should be possible to write `addx` so that we do not have to pass a second argument to it inside `mutate(across())` and do not have to hard-code `dtmp$x` inside the function definition. Is this possible? In other words, is there a `something(x)` that will make the `x` expression inside the definition of `addx()` be evaluated in the environment of the current data frame (as defined inside `mutate(across(data,...))`)?

The structure of a solution would look like

```
addx = function(col){col + Something(x)}
dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), addx))
```

*Example use case: some functions we might use to modify variables may reference *many* other variables inside the data frame and those functions may be used many times in the code. Writing out `arg1=var1, arg2=var2, arg3=var3,...` is a mess.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract `x` value from `cur_data()` which would also work when  you group the data.

```
library(dplyr)

dtmp = tibble(x = 1:4, y = 10, z = 20)

# Function to pass to mutate(across())
addx = function(col) {col + cur_data()$x}

dtmp %>% mutate(across(c(y,z), addx))

#      x     y     z
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    11    21
#2     2    12    22
#3     3    13    23
#4     4    14    24
```

If you need the function to **reference a grouping variable**, use `cur_data_all()`, instead.

Comment: `cur_data()` is the function I vaguely remembered and was struggling to find. I think I was thrown off by the existence of `current_vars()` and kept trying to find another `current_something()` function.

Comment: Can you think of a way to modify this question to make it more useful to others? I thought of saying something like “how to write a function that will reference the current data inside a `dplyr` verb”, but that was not specific enough because there are cases where you can just use `.` for that.

Comment: Maybe someway to specify current data which may be grouped?